# SQL : Left join with grouped joined rows

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables:

- `users` containing all my users with common attributes
- `metas` holding all dynamic attributes in a one to many relation, (Fyi I cant merge theses attributes into the `users` table because they can be created / deleted on the fly).

## users

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | j@d.com |
| 2 | Jane | a@d.com |

## metas

| user_id | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | created_at | "2021-01-01" |
| 1 | logged_at | "2021-01-01" |
| 2 | created_at | "2021-01-01" |

## Problem

I want to build a SQL query resulting with something like below, so I can have some where and orders on user metadatas.

| id | name | email | created_at | logged_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | j@d.com | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | Jane | a@d.com | 2021-01-01 | NULL |

## Progression

I managed to build a result but with only one meta (the `created_at`) but not `logged_at`, because I can't group many meta rows for the same user.

```sql
SELECT users.*, CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(value) AS DATE) as created_at
FROM users
LEFT JOIN metas on users.id = metas.user_id and metas.name = 'created_at'
ORDER BY created_at desc
```

## Constraints

- It should be done in a single query and can't be done from the code side.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use a `PIVOT` for this?

Comment: I did not know about the "pivot" concept. In MySQL there is no pivot mechanism but can be worked around with the @hashed tomato solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the same table twice.

```
SELECT users.*, 
  CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(m1.value) AS DATE) as created_at,
  CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(m2.value) AS DATE) as logged_at
FROM users
LEFT JOIN metas m1 on users.id = m1.user_id and m1.name = 'created_at'
LEFT JOIN metas m2 on users.id = m2.user_id and m2.name = 'logged_at'
ORDER BY created_at desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a pivot

```
select *
from
(
    select u.id,u.name as user_name,u.email,m.name as meta_name,m.value
    from @tUsers as u
    left join @tMetas as m on u.id=m.user_id
) as q
pivot 
( 
    max(q.value) for q.meta_name in ([Created_At],[Logged_At])
) as pvt
order by pvt.id
```